# What GNU makefile rule can ensure the version of make is at least v3.82?

Tags: version, gnu-make

I have a makefile that gives a non-obvious failure when an older version of gmake is used.  I'd like to have a rule that checks the version is at least version 3.82 or later.  I've gotten as far as the following rule, but the comparison is brittle, I really want a comparison allowing for later versions too:

```
GMAKE_VERSION :=  $(shell gmake --version | head -n 1 | sed 's/GNU Make //')

.PHONY: testMake
testMake:
    @if [ "$(GMAKE_VERSION)" != "3.82" ];               \
    then                                \
        echo >&2 "Unexpected gmakefile version "        \
            "$(GMAKE_VERSION), expecting 3.82 or later.";   \
        false;                          \
    fi
```

What GNU makefile rule can ensure the version of make is at least v3.82?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how I would implement it:

```
# Check Make version (we need at least GNU Make 3.82). Fortunately,
# 'undefine' directive has been introduced exactly in GNU Make 3.82.
ifeq ($(filter undefine,$(value .FEATURES)),)
$(error Unsupported Make version. \
    The build system does not work properly with GNU Make $(MAKE_VERSION), \
    please use GNU Make 3.82 or above.)
endif
```

The check is based on testing `.FEATURES` built-in variable. From GNU Make 3.82 [NEWS file](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/make/NEWS?revision=2.109&root=make&view=markup):

> New make directive: `undefine` allows you to undefine a variable so that
>     it appears as if it was never set. Both `$(flavor)` and `$(origin)` functions
>     will return 'undefined' for such a variable. **To detect this feature search
>     for `undefine` in the `.FEATURES` special variable.**